# Error when attempting to call function from button in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

As a beginner in wxpthon, I'm creating a simple login script that creates two buttons: one to open a window for the user to create an account, and one for them to register an account. My relevant code is:

```
 yesbutton = wx.Button(panel, label="Yes,  I wish to log in", pos=(50,150), size=(150,60))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, Login.login(Login), yesbutton)


 nobutton = wx.Button(panel, label="No,  I wish to register", pos=(270,150), size=(150,60))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, Register.register(Register), nobutton)


class Login:


    def login(self):
        print("login")


class Register:

    def register(self):
        print("register")
```

However when I run this code i get:

> TypeError: unbound method login() must be called with Login instance
>   as first argument (got classobj instance instead)

I've looked a lot for this answer, but I can't make any solutions work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your functions `Login.login()` and `Register.register()` take no arguments, but you're passing the `Login` and `Register` classes into them. Your second line should instead be:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, Login.login, yesbutton)
```

You don't need the parentheses after `Login.login` in this case since it's within the `Bind` function. Similarly adjust your other binding.

**Edit:** You also need to instantiate a `Login` object and a `Register` object before calling anything from those classes. Unfortunately I don't have access to wxPython at the moment and can't test it, but try this:

**Edit 2:** This will also pass the event into the function, so make sure the functions you are calling account for this.

```
yesbutton = wx.Button(panel, label="Yes,  I wish to log in", pos=(50,150), size=(150,60))
log = Login()
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, log.login, yesbutton)


nobutton = wx.Button(panel, label="No,  I wish to register", pos=(270,150), size=(150,60))
reg = Register()
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, reg.register, nobutton)


class Login:

    def login(self, evt):
        print("login")

class Register:

    def register(self, evt):
        print("register")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the lambda function in doing this?

eg: `self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda: <INSTANCE OF LOGIN>.login(), yesbutton)`

You would do the same thing for rthe register command

Answer (score 0):

When you use the bind function, the second parameter where you pass your function is called the "handler". By default, the only thing that is passed to this function is a wx Event. The correct syntax for doing this (using your code) would be

`self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, Login.login, yesbutton)`

For future reference, if you want to call a function that does not take an event as a parameter on an Event, do this:

`self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: Login.login(), yesbutton)`